# noisy validation loss (versus epoch) when using batch normalization

Tags: validation, deep-learning, keras, batch-normalization

I am using the following model in Keras:

Input/conv1/conv2/maxpool/conv3/conv4/maxpool/conv5/conv6/maxpool/FC1/FC2/FC3/softmax(2 nodes).

When I use Batch Normalization after each activation (Wx) and before non-linearity ReLu(Wx), the loss and accuracy of the validation is noisy (Red=Training_set / Blue=validation_set):

[image: Fig1- with BN.]

If I remove the BN layers, then validation loss is as smooth as the training loss [image: Fig2].

I've tried the following (but did not work):

1.Increase batch size from 64 to 256
2. Decrease learning rate
3. add L2-reg and/or dropout of different amplitude
4. train/validation split ratio: 20%, 30%.
FYI, the dataset is the kaggle cats&dogs images.

Comment: Could you try to run it for more epochs? `20` is a small number.

Comment: I actually ran it for 60 epochs at first, but then reduced the EPOCH to 20 to tests with different L2-reg, batch_sz etc (would like to share the plot of loss vs EPOCHs for that case, but not sure if I can attach an image in a comment!!). Note that the class balance in the validation set is same as in the training set: 50% cats / 50% dogs.

Comment: I have a similar problem but with RNNs. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: It looks like it is not using the estimated mean and variance of the population when predicting. This could be due to an older version or Keras, doing prediction in small batches, or possibly something to do with the momentum parameter.